# semantic-release Github multi-platform publish

Tags: electron-builder, semantic-release, github-release

I have an *Electron* app that I want to publish with [`semantic-release`](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io).

I need to create a `matrix` in *Github Action* to build the app on different platforms:

```yaml
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [windows-latest, ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
```

Now, if I run `semantic-release` **before** the build, it creates a *Release* in Github, and the build can't update an existing *Release*.

If I want to run `semantic-release` **after** the build,

1. I don't know the **new version** for the build, and I don't know if I need to run the build anyway.
2. How can I publish the build artifacts with `semantic-release`?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `semantic-release` in dry mode (`--dry-run`) and it'll not create and publish a release. Then just get the next version number via grep.

```bash
export NEXT_VERSION=$(npx semantic-release --dry-run --branches main | grep -oE 'The next release version is [1234567890\.]+' | grep -oE '[1234567890\.]+')
echo $NEXT_VERSION
```