# semantic-release deploy electron-builder to Github Release

Tags: github-actions, electron-builder, semantic-release, github-release

The [`semantic-release`](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io) and [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build/) are both publishing a *Github Release*.

I want to combine them, so `semantic-release` will be responsible for the release **version** and **CHANGELOG**, but the `electron-builder` will be responsible for the **publishing artifacts**.

- `semantic-release` -> `electron-builder`

  If you run `semantic-release` first, it will **release** a new release in Github.

  After that, using the version from `semantic-release` and running `electron-builder`, it will create a **draft** release with the same tag as the **released** release from `semantic-release`.
- `[semantic-release dry-run]` -> `electron-builder` -> `semantic-release`

  You can run `semantic-release` in a *dry run* to get the expected **version**, then run `electron-builder` to create a **draft** release.

  Then, you expect `semantic-release` to **update** the draft release and **release** it, but it didn't happen, and `semantic-release` release **other** new release.
- `semantic-release` -> `electron-builder releaseType=release`

  The third option is to run `semantic-release` and let it create a release.

  Then, you run `electron-builder` with [`releaseType=release`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish.html#githuboptions), to **release** instead of **draft**.

  In this way, the new release is created (by `semantic-release`) and the artifact deployed to the same release (by `electron-builder`).

  **The only problem is that the release is first created, and then the artifacts are added**. This might be a problem when using [AutoUpdate](https://www.electron.build/auto-update.html).

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625579/semantic-release-github-multi-platform-publish, but I divided them to two questions to solve different problems.